# What is advantage of embedding HTTP server in iOS app?

Tags: ios, http

In linked in implementation, they have HTTP server implemented in iOS app. What could be the reason behind this architecture, if uiwebview already handles the HTML loading and rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have a HTTP server embedded as much as they are just making *very liberal* use of UIWebView and the features of HTML5.

And the benefits of doing this are that they only have to write a relatively general implementation of the LinkedIn mobile interface in HTML5 and those changes get carried across to iOS, Android, Windows Mobile, and whatever other mobile platforms support HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of apps with an embedded HTTP server. This is used as one possible method for importing/exporting data to/from the app. The user connects to the app from their computer's web browser to the server on their iOS device. The user can then download a file from or upload a file to the app. I added this feature before iOS supported file sharing via iTunes and the Documents directory. It's now one of several ways to get data to/from the app.